# Как выполнять Ajax запрос только для конкретной $(this) кнопки если кнопок много? Сейчас данные загружаются всем кнопкам с классом .loadmore_gs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ajax, ajax-load

Использую такой скрипт для вордпресс:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($){
                    $('.loadmore_gs').click(function(){
                        $('.cssload-container').css({'display' : 'block'});
                        $(this).text('Загрузка...');
                        var data = {
                            'action': 'loadmore',
                            'query': true_posts,
                            'page' : current_page
                        };
                        $.ajax({
                            url:ajaxurl,
                            data:data,
                            type:'POST',
                            success:function(data){
                                if( data ) { 
                                    $('.loadmore_gs').text('Показать еще...').before(data);
                                    $('.cssload-container').css({'display' : ''});
                                    current_page++;
                                    if (current_page == max_pages) $(".loadmore_gs").remove();
                                } else {
                                    $('.loadmore_gs').remove();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

По ID назначать не вариант т.к. блоков может быть несколько.
Как выполнять $('.loadmore_gs').click(function() только при клике на текущую кнопку? Куда ввести переменную var $this = $(this); или что то подобное?

Comment: вместо `success:function(data)` сделать стерлочную функцию и тогда можно писать `$(this);` прямо в success, в ином случае придётся писать `$this = $(this);` до `ajax` а потом в success  использовать $this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например вы можете записать текущий ивент в переменную и потом работать с ним

```
 jQuery(function($){
     $('.loadmore_gs').click(function(){
         let $this = $(this);
         
         $('.cssload-container').css({'display' : 'block'});
         $this.text('Загрузка...');
         
         let data = {
             'action': 'loadmore',
             'query': true_posts,
             'page' : current_page
         };
         $.ajax({
             url:ajaxurl,
             data:data,
             type:'POST',
             success:function(data){
                 if( data ) { 
                     $this.text('Показать еще...').before(data);
                     $('.cssload-container').css({'display' : ''});
                     current_page++;
                     if (current_page == max_pages) $this.remove();
                 } else {
                    $this.remove();
                 }
            }
        });
    });
});
```